# Tracking of a manually marked point in the next frames of a video

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-matching

I have to track a point that is being manually marked in the first frame. The location of this marked point is to be located in the next consecutive frames of the video. The video is grayscale (fluorescent video)
Which algorithm or technique should I apply?

Comment: Try openTLD or it's enhanced version CMT tracker it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would say KLT (Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi) is your best bet. See this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html) in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks Dima, KLT is under my consideration but when I go through the literature I found it is used for shapes that do not change with time. But my  video is actually an x-ray of spinal cord. I have to track the six discs (square in shape) having translation, rotation motion along with the disc shape change in some of the frames with movement.
Thank you for your comment and guidance.
More you could suggest more would be beneficial.

Comment: In that case, you are not really tracking a single point. Can you find the discs in each frame?  Maybe using intensity-based segmentation and morphology?  Then you can try associating the discs across frames based on proximity, shape, and size...  You could try the Kalman filter, if you can come up with a reasonable motion model...

Comment: I had the same point of view for the problem solution that first to go for segmentation. But my supervisor is insisting to use the corner point features of the disc and use those features in the next frame for tracking the point. As the intensity difference between the disc boundary and background is good which features of the point should I use to trace it?

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

What kind of apparent motion are you trying to track? Is it mostly a pure translation, or do you expect significant rotation/streching/scaling frame to trame (e.g. are you trying to track a spoke in the wheel of a car?)

If you can live with pure translation, KLT, as Dima suggested, is one worth trying. However, if the size of the used pattern and the inter-frame displacements are largish (meaning you may have to search in largish windows), FFT-based normalized correlation may be a winner (see J.P. Lewis's [classic paper](http://scribblethink.org/Work/nvisionInterface/nip.pdf) for details).

If you need a more complex motion model, I'd first try [the affine extension of the KLT](http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b04/algo_affine_tracking.pdf). I personally did use that one to track spokes of car wheels.

Comment: Thanks for guidance. Its actually an x-ray video of spine so the motion is complex the discs of vertebra translates, rotates and their shape varies with movement. Six square like discs needs to be tracked.
I shall try the above mentioned techniques. If any thing you can suggest it would be very helpful.